# Querying for a String inside a Set in Spring Data MongodDB repository

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have Set inside a class as follows:

```
@Document(collection="Foo")
public class Foo {

   @Id
   String id;

   @Indexed 
   Set<String> bars = new HashSet<String>();
}
```

I then have the following repository for it:

```
public interface FooRepository  extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Foo, String>{

   public List<Foo> findByBars(String bar);

}
```

The code works fine (all Junits I have for it work) but, unfortunately, I get a compilation warning:

> FooRepository.java    Parameter type (String) does not match domain class
>   property definition (Set).    Unknown Spring Data Problem

If I change the parameter from "String bar" to "Set< String> bar" the compilation warning goes away. But I do want to query with String and not have to create a Set. Any idea how to resolve?

Comment: what you want to get, i don't get you?

Comment: I want to get all Foo's that have a Bar "xx" in them. So a match on one of the items in the set. Not necessarily all.

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: <spring.data.mongodb>1.8.4.RELEASE</spring.data.mongodb>

Comment: Did you try rename your method `findByBarsIn`?

Comment: Works! Thanks @barbakini. Please add an answer so I can give you credit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `bars` is an array you should rename your method like `findByBarsIn`. With **In** spring can understand you are not trying to query `bars` with exact match but `bars` is an array and you want query this array with a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Method `findByBars` generate a query by field `bars`. Parameter `bar` should have same type with `bars`.

Comment: Yes. I know that. And that is my intention. The code works, I just want to rid of the warning.